# mini cart is not showing count and product added in cart?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, mini-cart, magento2minicart

I've a custom phtml file where I;ve added the below code and still cart shows empty.

```
   <?php  echo $this->getLayout()
        ->createBlock('Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar')
        ->setTemplate('Magento_Checkout::cart/minicart.phtml')
        ->toHtml(); ?>
</li>
```

[image: Cart Image]

Answer (score 0):

Well , first of all, its not best practice to render blocks like that. The correct way is to add the blocks on the layout xmls like `default.xml`.

For the problem you have, if you look in the layout file where it is getting declared `/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout/default.xml` you will see:

```
<referenceContainer name="header-wrapper">
        <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar" name="minicart" as="minicart" after="logo" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/minicart.phtml">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="types" xsi:type="array"/>
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="minicart_content" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/minicart</item>
                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/minicart/content</item>
                            </item>
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="subtotal.container" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">subtotalContainer</item>
                                    </item>
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="subtotal" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/minicart/subtotal</item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                                <item name="extra_info" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">extraInfo</item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                                <item name="promotion" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">promotion</item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
            <container name="minicart.addons" label="Mini-cart promotion block"/>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
```

As you can see it has many arguments which needs to be included which you are not. Move the already available or create the same with different name and render it on a block you like.

Comment: I want to show minicart on other location, How can I achieve this?

Comment: Here https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html  explains how you can use layout.xml to configure where different blocks gonna appear. Usually you use `<move element="name.of.an.element" destination="name.of.destination.element" as="new_alias" after="name.of.element.after" before="name.of.element.before"/>
` and move your element which is the name of the minicart block and the destination is in which block you want to show it.  After that inside block you can echo the block with `$block->getChildHtml('{block alias}')`

Comment: Actually I'm using custom theme and I'm calling like the above but It comes empty .

Comment: Well the block needs all the arguments  with the parent item as `jsLayout` and the children. If you want to do it with the way you mentioned in the question you have to create an array with all the name values of the arguments and pass it as  `<?php  echo $this->getLayout()
        ->createBlock('Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar')
        ->setTemplate('Magento_Checkout::cart/minicart.phtml')
        ->setData('jsLayout',{$array})
        ->toHtml(); ?>
</li>`

Comment: Hi Vyacgeskavm after using the above code I'm getting error->  Error filtering template: Notice: Undefined variable: array in ('jsLayout',{$array})->toHtml();

Comment: Hi Vyacgeskavm after using the above code I'm getting error->  Error filtering template: Notice: Undefined variable: array in ('jsLayout',{$array})->toHtml(); Actually I'm using php7.4 so I think I need to use like ('jsLayout',[$array])->toHtml(); but here I've one question where to define $array?

Comment: The {$array} is the placeholder to create a variable which is array and has the data I mentioned. It has nothing to do with the PHP version.  Please read more how magento uses layout xml, https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html .

Comment: I'm not getting data in this div---->                                                                                
 <div id="minicart-content-wrapper" data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'">
                <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            </div>